# Android: Can't get http data with AsyncTask

Tags: android, http, parsing, android-asynctask, get

I'm creating a news app. Usaly when I getting HTTP data it works fine, but now in my app I'm using RecyclerView+CardView and I've (I supose some kind of logical error because of it). I've tried to use different libraries like OkHttp and Retrofit but the doesn't work as well. I completley sure that I've got a core misunderstanding.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private List<Message> list;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
    String result = null;
    try {

        result = task.execute("https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=(MyApi)").get();

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (ExecutionException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    AtomicReference<MyCustomAdapter> adapter = null;
    adapter.set(new MyCustomAdapter(initData(result)));
    Log.i("result","Heh "+result);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter.get());
}

private List<Message> initData(String myDataString) {
    representData(myDataString);
    return list;
}
private void representData(String myJSONDataString){
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    JsonObject rootObj = parser.parse(myJSONDataString).getAsJsonObject();
    JsonArray articlesArray = rootObj.getAsJsonArray("articles");
    for (JsonElement aa : articlesArray) {
        JsonObject articleObj = aa.getAsJsonObject();
        String title = articleObj.get("title").getAsString();
        String description = articleObj.get("description").getAsString();
        list.add(new Message(title,description));
    }
}
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        String result = "";
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        try {

            url = new URL(urls[0]);

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

            int data = reader.read();

            while (data != -1) {

                char current = (char) data;

                result += current;

                data = reader.read();

            }

            return result;

        }
        catch(Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

            return "Failed";

        }


    }

}
```

}
LogCat

```
05-21 07:19:48.414 12126-12126/com.example.gmachine.mynewsapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.gmachine.mynewsapp, PID: 12126
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gmachine.mynewsapp/com.example.gmachine.mynewsapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference.set(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2804)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2875)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1578)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6623)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference.set(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.gmachine.mynewsapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:61)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6910)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2757)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2875) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1578) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6623) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832) 
05-21 07:19:48.461 12126-12126/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 12126 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Using `execute().get()` will block your main thread until the task is finished!

Comment: @Barns, that would completely go against the use of AsyncTask, why should the main thread be blocked during a network operation? Isn't avoiding that the actual work of AsyncTask?

Comment: @KoushikShomChoudhury That's what .get() does.  It waits until an AsyncTask is finished.  What you want to do is call execute() without .get()-  that will actually do it in the background.  Calling .get() generally means the person doesn't know what he's doing and can't write multithreaded code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

`AtomicReference<MyCustomAdapter> adapter = null;`

to

`AtomicReference<MyCustomAdapter> adapter = new AtomicReference<>();`

Also, please read your error log carefully next time. It clearly states that you have a `NullPointerException`

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference.set(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Explanation: You are creating an instance of `AtomicReference` named as **adapter** but you are not initializing it. So it is by default initialized to null. So when, you call `set` on a null instance a `NullPointerException` is thrown. To avoid this, initialize the `AtomicReference adapter` with `new AtomicReference<>()` as said in the answer.

Comment: @KoushikShomChoudhury ...By the look of it, he knows how to initialize. I'm stating the fact that he didn't read his error message. The answer is intended in improve the quality of his code by reading his errors log, not by explaining something that he already knows. However, thank you for stopping by :)

Comment: The comment is also meant for other users (mainly newbies) who may not have the same knowledge as you. So, if this answer is marked as correct, the explanation flies with it too!